# Platform-specific implemenation not set // Implementing AdColony Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, adcolony

sorry i'm kind of new to developing mobile apps. I've been trying to implement AdColony into my unity project. I've imported the files and configured the setting

```
    AdColony.AppOptions options = new AdColony.AppOptions ();
    AdColony.Ads.Configure ("app_id", options, zoneIDs);
```

however, every time I try to launch the project I keep getting the same error message (displayed below) and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

```
Platform-specific implemenation not set
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
AdColony.Ads:get_SharedInstance() (at Assets/AdColony/Scripts/AdColony.cs:340)
AdColony.Ads:Configure(String, AppOptions, String[]) (at Assets/AdColony/Scripts/AdColony.cs:144)
```

Something to do with sharedGameObject I think but it's really frustrating. Sorry if I'm an absolute noob but please any help would be much appreciated <3

Comment: replace "app_id" with your app_id

Comment: how did i not see that... damn! thanks.